# Why is pip trying to reach pypi.python.org when pip.conf specifies elsewhere?

Tags: python, pip

My org uses artifactory, an on-premises package repository manager. Artifactory provides a feature called Remote Repositories which provides proxying and caching capabilities for remote repositories, we use this for proxying and caching access to PyPi (see [PyPi Repositories](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/PyPI+Repositories) for more details).

In order to use this remote repository one has to add an entry to pip.conf. I have done this on a box onto which I need to install some machines however when I issue a pip command (in my case its `sudo -E pip install --ignore-installed pip setuptools wheel`) pip appears to be ignoring what's in pip.conf and instead is trying to get to https://pypi.python.org.

Here is a transcript of what I have just run:

```
$ cat /etc/pip.conf  
[global]  
index-url = https://username:password@artifactory.myorg.com/artifactory/api/pypi/pypi-remote/simple  

$ sudo -E pip
install --ignore-installed pip setuptools wheel  
Downloading/unpacking pip  
  Cannot fetch index base URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/   
  Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement pip  
Cleaning up...  
No distributions at all found for pip  
Storing debug log for failure in /home/jamiet/.pip/pip.log  

$ cat /home/jamiet/.pip/pip.log   
Downloading/unpacking pip   
   Getting page https://pypi.python.org/simple/pip/
   Could not fetch URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/pip/: connection error: ('Connection aborted.', error(101, 'Network is unreachable'))
  Will skip URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/pip/ when looking for download links for pip  
   Getting page https://pypi.python.org/simple/   Could not
fetch URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/: connection error:
('Connection aborted.', error(101, 'Network is unreachable'))
  Will skip URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/ when looking for download
links for pip
  Cannot fetch index base URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/  
  URLs to search for versions for pip:
* https://pypi.python.org/simple/pip/  
  Getting page https://pypi.python.org/simple/pip/  
  Could not fetch URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/pip/: connection error: ('Connection
aborted.', error(101, 'Network is unreachable'))  
  Will skip URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/pip/ when looking for download link for pip  
  Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement pip  
Cleaning up... No distributions at all found for pip
```

Can anyone explain to me why pip is attempting to reach https://pypi.python.org/simple/pip/ when pip.conf is instructing it to go somewhere different?

Comment: please use code formatting for logs, not `<blockquote>`

Comment: gotcha, thank you very much for taking the time to change it.

Comment: I just guess that, If You are using it with `sudo` so maybe in the `root` user config there is config which overrides the `site-wide` config. The config s read in given order `site -> user -> venv` and You are setting the config file just to override the site

Comment: That's possible. I shall look into it. thank you.

Comment: Just realised the default version of pip used on this VM is 1.5.6 which came out in May 2014, that strikes me as being rather old. Is it possible that pip.conf was not supported in this version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We were using an old version of pip, 1.5.6, which came out in May 2014. When we specified the index-url on the command-line `sudo -E pip install --index-url https://username:password@artifactory.myorg.com/artifactory/api/pypi/pypi-remote/simple --ignore-installed pip setuptools wheel` everything worked as expected so we're assuming that this old version of pip does not use pip.conf or, if it does, it doesn't use it in the same way.

Once that command (which upgrades pip) completed successfully subsequent calls to pip in the same script did not require `--index-url` specifying because they used pip.conf as expected.